# Lightning Component to invoke Process builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, process-builder

I am hoping to invoke a process using lightning components but I don't know where to begin.

How can I create a component that fires up a Proces Builder.

The outcome I am looking for is a custom button on object Opportunity that when clicked should launch a certain Process.

If you know please let me know, thanks!

Comment: That's not how it works. A process is automatically invoked from a record creation or update. It doesn't matter where the event is coming from.

Comment: hmm I know there are other ways of doing this I just want to be able to use the component so its much more customizable that's why but I guess there is no way  of doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a Lighting Component or Process Builder to do that. You can create a Flow to handle the automation and call the Flow from a button.

Comment: Thanks @nicholas Savini, really appreciate your input I know there are others ways of doing it but I really want it to to be done from the component for the customization and the process speed of it. Wouldn't there be a way to invoke this PB from the JS of components controller?

Comment: You can't and wouldn't want to call a PB that way. I believe you can only call Flows from Aura components at the moment. But again, this is unnecessary. You're not going to really get any speed or process benefits from calling a Flow from Aura/LWC, unless you actually need features not available in Flows. Calling a Flow directly from a button is likely going to be faster and easier than calling an Aura component from a button and calling a Flow from that component.